# CSS nth-child to create sequence odd even

Tags: html, css

i know there is so many question about this, but i think this is a new question about nth child. i tried to build multiple profile page with an order

1. odd goes left even goes right
2. odd n1 = background1(1) even n1 = backround2(1)
3. odd n2 = background1(2) even n2 = backround2(2)
4. odd n3 = background1(3) even n3 = backround2(3)
5. it simply cyan magenta yellow and always repeat. b1cyan left, b2magenta right, b1yellow left, b2cyan right, b1magenta left, b2yellow right and so on.

```css
.wrapper{
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;}

    .items{
    width:100%;}

    .items:nth-child(odd){
    text-align:left;}
    .items:nth-child(even){
    text-align:right;}

    .items:nth-child(odd):not(:nth-child(3n+1)){
     background:cyan;
     background-size:100% 100%;
     }
    .items:nth-child(even):not(:nth-child(3n+1)){
     background:magenta;
     background-size:100% 100%;
    }.items:nth-child(odd):not(:nth-child(3n+2)){
     background:yellow;
     background-size:100% 100%;
     }
    .items:nth-child(even):not(:nth-child(3n+2)){
     background:cyan;
     background-size:100% 100%;
     }
    .items:nth-child(odd):not(:nth-child(3n+3)){
     background:magenta;
     background-size:100% 100%;
     }
    .items:nth-child(even):not(:nth-child(3n+3)){
     background:yellow;
     background-size:100% 100%;
     }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="items">a</div>
        <div class="items">b</div>
        <div class="items">c</div>
        <div class="items">d</div>
        <div class="items">e</div>
        <div class="items">f</div>
        <div class="items">g</div>
        <div class="items">h</div>
        <div class="items">i</div>
        <div>
```

it appears that `.items:nth-child(odd):not(:nth-child(3n+1))` means

an odd number in order (3x0)+1 items should be doing this and so on but. it didn't work as i thot.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you desire.

```css
.wrapper{
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;}

    .items{
    width:100%;}

    .items:nth-child(odd){
    text-align:left;}
    .items:nth-child(even){
    text-align:right;}

    .items:nth-child(odd):nth-child(3n+1) {
      background: cyan;
    }
    .items:nth-child(even):nth-child(3n+2) {
      background: magenta;
    }
    .items:nth-child(odd):nth-child(3n+3) {
      background: yellow;
    }

    .items:nth-child(even):nth-child(3n+4) {
      background: cyan;
    }
    .items:nth-child(odd):nth-child(3n+5) {
      background: magenta;
    }
    .items:nth-child(even):nth-child(3n+6) {
      background: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="items">a</div>
        <div class="items">b</div>
        <div class="items">c</div>
        <div class="items">d</div>
        <div class="items">e</div>
        <div class="items">f</div>
        <div class="items">g</div>
        <div class="items">h</div>
        <div class="items">i</div>
        <div>
```

Comment: it's not. but thx for your contribution. i will update my question. please check. a minute please

Comment: @riverrhun I have updated the CSS. Please let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: man this is true. but can u explain what's going on here? 3n+number what it suppose to mean, i tried to copy paste your code to my local host and the result has changed.

Comment: forgot it my last question man, i forgot to wrap my div's. thx man

Comment: (3n+number) will select every third one starting with the first one. You have to set `:nth-child(odd):nth-child(3n+1)` to make sure it skips the even ones, I think. That is also why you have to set six properties. I am glad it is working!